# rails select only 2 columns error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

script/console output:

```
>> User.find(:first, :select => '`email`, `pass`, `login`, `id`')
=> #<User pass: "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e", email: "fakemail@bla-bla-bla.com">
>> User.find(:first, :select => '`pass`, `login`, `id`')
=> #<User login: "ostap", pass: "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e">
```

how i can fix it?
Unix hosting, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.5, MySQL 5.1.46

in mysql console all fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing ":select => '`pass`, `login`, `id`'" to `:select => 'email, pass, login, id'`; i.e. remove the backticks around the fields. I think the backticks in your argument are throwing off the select. Here is the [API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class) for the find command that lead me to that conclusion.

Comment: `>> User.find(:first, :select => 'email, pass, login, id')`  
`=> #<User pass: "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e", email: "fakemail@bla-bla-bla.com">`  
`>> User.find(:first)`  
`=> #<User id: 1, login: "ostap">`  Its doesnt work...

Comment: I don't know if this is a pattern but for some suspicious reason only the first two columns are shown. No matter what you selected. Did you check if the attributes are set actually? Maybe they are not shown only.

Comment: @iltempo what attributes? and how i can check this?

Comment: Call `User.find(:first, :select => 'email, pass, login, id').login`.

Comment: `>> User.find(:first, :select => 'email, pass, login, id').login
ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: login
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:244:in send
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:244:in method_missing
        from (irb):1
`

Comment: activerecord cant parse mysql query result or what problem? how i can fix this?

Comment: fix: just add require 'mysql' to environment.rb